# Why does my $http.post return a 400 error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I fairly new to MEAN, so sorry if this question is so obvious. I want to send an email to a contact when they click a send button. My code for handling a send email is using a post I am currently using a SendGrid Nodejs API to send the email. The problem is I keep running into a 400 Post Error.

[This is the error I get in my Google Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0tx6.png)

[This is the error I get in my server terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPWuz.png)

This is in my controller.js:

```
$scope.send = function(contact) {
    console.log("Controller: Sending message to:"+ contact.email);
    $http.post('/email', contact.email).then(function (response) {
          //  return response;
          refresh();
        });
    };
```

this code is in my server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
//require the mongojs mondule
var mongojs =  require('mongojs');
//which db and collection we will be using
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']);
//sendgrid with my API Key
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid")("APIKEY");
var email = new sendgrid.Email();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//location of your styles, html, etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.post('/email', function (req, res) {
         var curEmail = req.body;
          console.log("Hey I am going to send this person a message:" + curEmail);
      var payload   = {
        to      : 'test@gmail.com',
        from    : 'test1@gmail.com',
        subject : 'Test Email',
        text    : 'This is my first email through SendGrid'
      }
      sendgrid.send(payload, function(err, json) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(json);
      });
    });
```

Currently the email is hard coded but I will make the change after I fix the post issue. If you could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: seem like you didn't respond the `$http.post('/email', contact.email)`

Comment: Check the request headers from your POST request. The error you're getting is common when you're trying to read a Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded as a Content-Type: application/json

Comment: When you provide your data in $http.post('/email', contact.email)... are you sure that contact.email is an object like { email: 'test@email.com'}.
According to the error, the problem is with the format of your request (client side mal formation).

Comment: I believe that the contact.email is correct because in the picture that I put I printed to google chrome console and it was the correct email

Comment: It seems that server things the data is json but since you sending email address as a string with first char being t (as per the error) it doesn't like it. Simply try to replace contact.email with `JSON.stringify({email: contact.email}};` to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're expecting the request body to contain JSON, with this line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Your error in your console says `Unexpected token`, which leads me to believe that body-parser encountered something it couldn't parse as JSON... probably a string. Which means that you sent your email as a string in the request body.

The easy fix would be to change how you're sending the request client-side:

```
var data = { email: 'some@email.com' }; // as opposed to just 'some@email.com'

$http.post('/email', data).then(refresh);
```

Comment: Would using `bodyparser.urlencoded()` instead of `bodyparser.json()` also work?

Comment: @GibryonBhojraj yep! The short answer is, the method used to parse the body needs to match the encoding of the body

Comment: Thanks, you so much it works! I am very new to developing in MEAN, I was staring at that piece of code for hours and you were able solve it so easily. Do you have any tips for debugging?

Comment: @WilliamPring glad I could help. In this specific case, you just have to read the ExpressJS docs and know which tools you're using (for example, body parser and how it works).

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$scope.send = function(contact) {
    console.log("Controller: Sending message to:"+ contact.email);
    $http.post('/email', contact).then(function (response) {
          //  return response;
          refresh();
        });
    };
```

and at server side

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser());
```